# How can I use a mix of Appengine's OpenID and facebook OAuth for authentication on AppEngine?

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, openid

Appengine supports federated login in which arbitrary OpenID providers can be added to the list of parties who can authenticate a user. However, some organizations - notably facebook - don't support OpenID. How is it possible to combine the OpenID support provided with GAE with mechanisms that can support OAuth or other login mechanisms?

More details (GAE Python assumed)...

My understanding of the way the OpenID mechanism is intended to work is as follows:

- I choose Federated Login from my app's configuration options
- This allows me to easily add OpenID providers through the
  `create_login_url` mechanism
- There is some Google session management used to track the authenticated
  user
- I control access to resources using `login: required` in my
  `app.yaml`

  - The session management will check if the user is authenticated
    before allowing access to these resources

The issue that I have is that I can't see how this approach fits with facebook's OAuth - if the resources are access controlled by Google (per `app.yaml`), where is it possible to insert facebook authentication?

Notes:

- I know that OpenID and OAuth are different - I am only interested in using facebook for authentication right now
- I'm sure there are quite a few different ways to deal with this - I'm just wondering if there is some standard approach/best practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a little bit of digging on this and my conclusion is that it is not possible to integrate the standard Appengine authentication mechanisms (ie those provided 'for free' with Appengine) with facebook's OAuth. More specifically, the `app.yaml` login controls can only relate to Google's standard mechanisms and there is no way to extend them to incorporate facebook OAuth. The reason for this is that Google's standard mechanisms control the sessions and there is no mechanism to add new session controls which are recognized by the `app.yaml` login controls.

It is, of course, possible to integrate Google Accounts and other login mechanisms with facebook's OAuth on Appengine, but to do this you need to replicate some of the functionality that Google provide in their standard authentication mechanisms (session mgmt specifically).

I've put up a more general question comparing the different social authentication options possible with Appengine as I think it's interesting/useful, but slightly out of scope in this question: it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660059/what-are-the-different-options-for-social-authentication-on-appengine-how-do-th)

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) framework which has a Facebook authentication [extension](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/auth/facebook/) that would allow your users to use their Facebook login to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks - good suggestion - I was aware of it, but had not looked at their solution. Does it integrate with Appengine's OpenID or did they end up rolling their own? I'll investigate further...

Comment: No, I think they pretty much roll their own. It does not use the builtin GAE OpenID support. But they do provide another OpenID extension that integrates into the same model, so you could use those to provide OpenID & Facebook OAuth support.

Comment: thanks for reply. Not gonna accept this yet, as I'd like some more detail on the solution, particularly as tipfy is no longer maintained.

Comment: I've had a quick look at tipfy - it's a nice framework. It supports authentication via a number of different services and it does its own session management. Interestingly, it can work with the Appengine authentication mechanisms, but this is to the exclusion of any other authentication mechanisms. From looking at tipfy, it seems that it is not possible to integrate with provided Appengine authentication mechanisms and bolt on OAuth/facebook - the solution involves rolling your own session management.